# PHP My files are not saving in the "uploads" directory

Tags: php

I have the folder in the same location of my codes but the files uploaded cannot be found in the designated directory. Any help is appreciated thank you.

This is my code for uploading:

`// A list of permitted file extensions`
`$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');`

`if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){`

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
    echo '{"status":"success"}';
    exit;
}
```

`}`

`echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;`

Comment: You should be checking the mime type using php `finfo()` class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
$status = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']);
var_dump($status);
```